# “sudo ls -a1 /home” Permission Denied

Tags: bash, sudo, apache-httpd, php, selinux

I have a php script that will run `exec("bash /path/to/list.sh $dir", $out);`

The contents of `list.sh` are...

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /usr/bin/ls -a1 $@ 2>&1
```

I have given apache permission to run ls as root. Here is the entry in the sudoers file.

```
www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/ls *
```

The script still can't access some folders however, such as `/home/.` Even though the permissions of `/home/` are

```
drwxr-xr-x.  40 root root  4096 Jun  5 08:24 home
```

from the `ls -l` command.

If I try to run `bash /path/to/list.sh /home` it returns the `sudo` lecture and then asks for password, despite the `NOPASSWD` entry. If I replace `www-data` in the `sudoers` file with `apache` or `all` it just fails completely with

```
/usr/bin/ls: cannot open directory /./home/: Permission denied.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: With "If I try to run `bash /path/to/list.sh /home`" you mean you run it as your user or after something like `su - www-data`? You should change `sudo /usr/bin/ls -a1 $@` to `sudo /usr/bin/ls -a1 "$@"` (doesn't solve your problem, though, just avoids new ones).

Comment: Replacing `www-data` in `sudoers` with `all` doesn't work because `sudo` recognizes `ALL` only. `all` is not interpreted as "all users" but as "the user all" which probably does not exist.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks, I'll do that!

Comment: @HaukeLaging I misspelled all in my question, I spelt it correctly in the sudoers file as `ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

The dot in `drwxr-xr-x.` shows that you are using SELinux. There is no problem with `sudo`, `ls` runs as `root`, but the kernel limits the permissions of the Apache process so much that not even `sudo` can escape from that jail.

I am not familiar enough with SELinux for telling you how to fix that but if you disable SELinux then that script should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've found out I need to enable `httpd_enable_homedirs`. Thanks!